# Список блоков без отступов от контейнера справа и слева

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Вот как нужно сверстать. Без отступов справа и слева от контейнера и с поддержкой IE9. Блоков может быть сколько угодно.
[image]

Стоит собственно вопрос: как?
Если делать на флексах, то вот до что у меня получилось:

```
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.child{
  width: 135px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Это максимально похожее, что у меня получилось. Кто-нибудь может подсказать в каком направлении хотя бы гуглить?

Comment: А можно растягивать блоки? если да то я знаю ответ.

Comment: на ie9 флексы как бы не работают...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример реализации того что вы хотели с помощью псевдокласса `:nth-child`:

```css
.block_container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 490px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #59728a;
}

.block{
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: grey;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.block:nth-child(5n){
    margin-right: 0;
}
.block:nth-child(5n+1){
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_container">
    
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    
</div>
```

Вот подробная документация про этот [псевдокласс](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child).

И там показано что оно работает начиная с верции `IE9`.

Comment: Что за свойство `heigh`

Comment: @Duoxx спасибо за примечание, букву пропустил, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @Duoxx и конечно голосовать против ваше право, но не вижу смысла за правильный ответ дать голос `-1`.

Comment: Извините, но я не голосовал против.

Comment: исправьте > верции

Comment: @Duoxx не понял что вы хотите сказать?

Comment: исправить в ответе ошибку